# Suppress elements from legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have following Chart:

```
Author_csv %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
      geom_jitter(aes(color=Autor), show.legend = F) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 7, y = 0, yend = 3.5, colour = "dashed"), linetype="dashed", size=0.3) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 7, y = 7, yend = 3.5, colour = "dashed"), linetype="dashed", size=0.3) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 7, y = 0, yend = 7, colour = "solid"), linetype="solid", size=0.3)
```

resulting in this graph:
[image: image.png]

I want to suppress the Jitter from the Legend. I only want to see my geom segment Lines with the label dashed/solid. How would i do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
geom_jitter(aes(color=Autor), show.legend = F)
```

Try using

```
geom_jitter(aes(fill=Autor), shape = 21, colour = "transparent", show.legend = FALSE)
```

Here is an example using the [palmerpenguins](https://allisonhorst.github.io/palmerpenguins/) dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
ggplot(aes(x=species, y=bill_length_mm)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill=island), shape = 21, colour = "transparent", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 3.5, y = 0, yend = 35, colour = "dashed"), linetype="dashed", size=0.3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 3.5, y = 70, yend = 35, colour = "dashed"), linetype="dashed", size=0.3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 3.5, y = 0, yend = 70, colour = "solid"), linetype="solid", size=0.3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>